# What is the most "bit-efficient" error detection method?

Tags: checksum, crc, error-detection

To detect a number of `n_errors` errors in a code of `n_total` bits length, we must sacrifice a certain number `n_check` of the bits for some sort of checksum.

My question is: What is the method, where I have to sacrifice the least number of bits `n_check` to detect a given number of errors `n_errors` in a code of `n_total` bits length.

If there is no general answer to this question, I would greatly appreciate some hints concerning methods for the following conditions:
`n_total=32`, `n_errors>1`and
obviously `n_check` should be as small as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [table of crcs](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/index.html) .

Comment: @rcgldr Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. If you would like to elaborate a little more upon the topic in an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: Click on "CRC Zoo", then "Notes Page" for an explanation. The maximum possible Hamming distance for a CRC depends on the number of one bits in the polynomial. The actual Hamming distance versus number of bits is mostly a brute force search, with some possible optimizations, but the larger ones require large scale parallel operations (or processors) to search for CRC with good Hamming distances versus the number of bits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, which was indeed helpful. However, my comment concerning a more elaborate answer had mainly the intent to help other readers and to have an answer which I can accept, so that this question is sort of closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to CRC Zoo notes:

http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/notes.html

If you look at the table for 3 bit crc:

http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/crc3.html

You can see that the second entry, 0xb => x^3 + x + 1, has HD (Hamming Distance) 3 for 4 data bits, for a total size of 7 bits. This can detect all 2 bit error patterns (out of 7 bits), but some 3 bit patterns will fail, an obvious case where all bits should be zero would be

```
0 0 0 1 0 1 1    (when it should be 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

This is a simple example where the number of 1 bits in the polynomial determined the maximum number of bit errors. To verify HD = 3 (2 bit errors detected) , all 21 cases of 7 bits total, 2 bits bad were checked.

If you check out 32 bit CRCs, you'll see that 0x04c11db7 (ethernet 802.3, has HD=6 (5 bit error detection) at 263 data bits => 263+32 = 295 total bits, while 0x1f4acfb13, has HD=6 at 32736 data bits => 32736+32 = 32768 total bits.

Here is a pdf article about a search for good CRCs:

https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/networks/dsn02/dsn02_koopman.pdf

---

Finding "good" CRCs for specific Hamming distances requires some knowledge about the process. For example, in the case of 0x1f4acfb13 with HD=6 (5 bad bit detection), there 314,728,365,660,920,250,368 possible combinations of 5 bits bad out of 32768 bits. However, 0x1f4acfb13 = 0x1f4acfb13 = 0xc85f*0x8011*0x3*0x3, and either of the 0x3 (x+1) terms will detect any odd number of error bits, which reduces the search to 4 bad bit cases. For the minimal size of a message that fails with this polynomial, the first and last bits will be bad. This reduces the searching down to just 2 of the 5 bits, which reduces the number of cases to about 536 million. Rather than calculating CRC for each bit combination, a table of CRCs can be created for each 1 bit in an otherwise all 0 bit message, and then the table entries corresponding to specific bits can be xor'ed to speed up the process. For a polynomial where it isn't the first and last bits, a table of CRC's could be generated for all 2 bit errors (assuming such a table fits in memory), then sorted, then checked for duplicate values (with sorted data, this only requires one sequential pass of the sorted table). Duplicate values would correspond to a 4 bit failure. Other situations will require different approaches, and in some cases, it's still time consuming.